# postgres performance on indexed status col vs timestamp col

Tags: postgresql

I have a pg table with about 20 million records. The first column contains the timestamp of the record's creation date. In the second column, a status (char) with 'ready' value is associated with 99% of the records, while a 'pending' value is associated with the rest. The two columns are indexed. Would it be faster to get all rows that are less than a specific timestamp (estimated 99% of the rows to be in the result) or to filter out all rows that have a 'pending' value?

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE status = 'ready'
```

vs

```
SELECT * from my_table where created_at < TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: The [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) will tell you

Comment: I recommend that you test the two queries and check the explain verbose , but I would say that searching for the status will be faster, because right away it will already eliminate 99% of the table, but to confirm this theory of mine, I recommend that you test .

Comment: @GabrielNexT actually both queries eliminates the same rows (1%), sorry if i was not clear, currently we indexed only the status column but thinking about the alternative as it covers more tasks rather than this specific scenario

Comment: If your query is retrieving 99% of the data there is no index that will help. An index is useful when you nee d a small percentage of the total rows, but with 99% a sequential scan will be much faster. You need to read every data block using an index you would need to read every index block and (most likely) every data block.

Comment: When you need 99% of the data in a table, you really don't want to use an index in the query plan. The index might be useful for other queries, but not for this one. Using an index scan would make this query slow.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries return 99% of the rows, using an index will be inefficient, so PostgreSQL will use a sequential scan instead. Consequently, the queries will perform almost identically. Any differences can be explained by one of the following factors:

- How much of the table is cached (the more, the faster).
- Which operator is faster: `=` for `text` or `<` for `timestamp`. My guess is that the latter operator is cheaper, since it only compares integers. This will make a difference, but that difference should be dwarfed by the cost of scanning the table and fetching all the columns.